# Error when an email is sent from Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: email, wildfly, wildfly-10

I configured my Wildfly (in **domain** mode) to send e-mails using Mail Session and Remote Socket Bindings.

After fill with the SMTP server, port 587, username, password and etc, I receive an error when the Wildfly try to send the e-mail:

```
Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

My credentials to authenticate in the SMTP server are correct.

I already try to flag the `Enable SSL?` for `true` in the Web Console, but I can't even connect in the server when I enable SSL.

I thinking the problem is that I need to enable TLS and not SSL. In the old Jboss I can do this using property, like this:

```
<property name="mail.smtp.tls" value="true"></property>
<property name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" value="true"></property>
```

But I can't see this possibility in Wildfly and I'm trying **to not edit** any XML.

So, how can I set the TLS for `true` in Wildfly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find the right command to apply in the domain controller. The big problem here is that the Web Console **doesn't show** the `Use TLS?` option...

After enter in the domain server, with the Jboss Client, you can **set** the TLS for `true`:

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=mail/mail-session=MyMailSession/server=smtp:write-attribute(name=tls, value=true)
```

You can see the change with this command:

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=mail/mail-session=MyMailSession/server=smtp:read-resource()
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "outbound-socket-binding-ref" => "mail-smtp",
        "password" => "PASSWORD",
        "ssl" => false,
        "tls" => true,
        "username" => "domain.com"
    }
}
```